# Insert string to style via JS

Tags: javascript, button, styles

anyone knows how I can add a string to the following button using javascript?

```
<button id="save0" class="lol">Click me</button>
```

I don't want to set up an attribute I just want to add "Disabled" say after class.

Thanks!

*Edit*
Set it up with attribute per Edit's comment, that just added the word "Disabled" to the style and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an attribute with an empty value. Like this:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("save0");
elem.setAttribute("disabled", "");
console.log(elem);
```

```html
<button id="save0" class="lol">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I was doing it backwards! THANKS!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's what attributes are for, in this case 'disabled'.

Check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp